# Running two functions at the same time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a function that animates a smooth scroll in vanilla Javascript so that the scroll behaviour can be experianced on all browsers.

I have two div's that I want to scroll simultaneously but running the function smoothScroll for both div1 and div2 in the provided snippet results in only the second div scrolling.

**Question**

Is it possible to run the function in a way that results in the divs scrolling at the same time?

Any help much appreciated and let me know if I you need any clarification.

```js
function smoothScroll(id, scroll, duration)
{
  let startTime = null;
  
  animation = (currentTime) => 
  {
    if(startTime === null) startTime = currentTime;
    const timeElapsed = currentTime - startTime;
    var run = ease(timeElapsed, 0, scroll, duration);
    document.getElementById(id).scrollLeft = run;
    if(timeElapsed < duration) requestAnimationFrame(animation);
  }
  
    ease = (t, b, c, d) => 
    {
      t /= d/2;
      if (t < 1) return c/2*t*t + b;
      t--;
      return -c/2 * (t*(t-2) - 1) + b;
    }
    
    requestAnimationFrame(animation);
  
}

smoothScroll('div1', 100, 1000);
smoothScroll('div2', 50, 1000);
```

```css
div{
  border: solid black 1px;
  display: flex;
  width: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <h1>Hello world!...................................................</h1>
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <h1>Hello world!...................................................</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Your variables are leaking out of scope: both `animation` and `ease` were used as global variables.

```js
function smoothScroll(id, scroll, duration)
{
    let startTime = null;
  
    const ease = (t, b, c, d) => 
    {
      t /= d/2;
      if (t < 1) return c/2*t*t + b;
      t--;
      return -c/2 * (t*(t-2) - 1) + b;
    }

    const animation = (currentTime) => 
    {
      if(startTime === null) startTime = currentTime;
      const timeElapsed = currentTime - startTime;
      var run = ease(timeElapsed, 0, scroll, duration);
      document.getElementById(id).scrollLeft = run;
      if(timeElapsed < duration)
      requestAnimationFrame(animation);
    }
    
    requestAnimationFrame(animation);
}

smoothScroll('div1', 100, 1000);
smoothScroll('div2', 50, 1000);
```

```css
div{
  border: solid black 1px;
  display: flex;
  width: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <h1>Hello world!...................................................</h1>
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <h1>Hello world!...................................................</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: oh, so not using const makes it a global variable?

Comment: `let`, `const` and `var` inside a function declare local variables. If a variable is not declared, it is an error in strict mode, or a global variable outside it. I strongly recommend using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) to catch these kinds of errors.